# Can I claim EIS tax for previous years?

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom, tax-deduction

I wasn't aware of EIS until recently. I have some small investments through crowdcube from 2019/2020 which I haven't claimed for in my tax return. Can I include them retrospectively on my current tax return?

Comment: When were the shares allotted?

Comment: @marktristan 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you have received an EIS3 (or EIS5) form for the investments?  (I doubt you can claim relief without one).

The government's current information on claiming EIS [here](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/enterprise-investment-scheme-income-tax-relief-hs341-self-assessment-helpsheet/hs341-enterprise-investment-scheme-income-tax-relief-2021)  (via [here](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/enterprise-investment-scheme-income-tax-relief-hs341-self-assessment-helpsheet)) states (my bold):

> If you made an investment in shares issued during the year for which
> you have not yet received a form EIS3 or EIS5, you cannot claim relief
> for that investment. You must wait until you have received a form. **If
> you receive the form after you’ve sent your tax return, complete the
> claim form inside the EIS3 or EIS5 and send it to us.**

Presumably HMRC will look at your income in the tax year the EIS3 form was actually for, and apply the relief appropriately (and presumably generating a refund to you).  As a general tax principle, you do not get to pick and choose the years in which you claim reliefs and to move things around for your convenience.  However I see the link above does include a "Tax relief for a different year – your choices" section; the only option seems to be to claim the relief in an even earlier - not later - year though.

Comment: This seems to be accurate. I have found other resources saying "you cannot carryo forward EIS relief" so the best thing seems to be to send off the forms and let HMRC apply it retrospectively.